# Method unavailable when using reflection - TargetInvocationError

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have been able to successfully execute other methods using reflection but I am now getting a `TargetInvocationException`.  Although the `TargetInvoationException` points me to the `methodInfo.Invoke` method, stepping through the code shows the exception occuring in the `Load` method when `SampleXMLToDataTable` is called.   The `SampleXMLToDataTable` is a `public static` method in the same class as `Load`.  The error is thrown as the code is attempting to enter the `SampleXMLToDataTable`.

Is there a problem calling methods from within other methods that are being called using reflection?

The code that calls via reflection:

```
 private Object CreateXMLDataLoaderInstance(string xml)
 {
  object o = null;

  Assembly demandAssembly = LoadSampleDemandAssembly();
  Type assemblyType = demandAssembly.GetType("SampleDemand.XMLDataLoader");
  MethodInfo methodInfo = assemblyType.GetMethod("Load");
  o = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType, new Object[1] { true });

  Object[] oParamArray2 = new Object[1];

  methodInfo.Invoke(o, new Object[1] { xml });//TargetInvocationException

  return o;
 }
```

And the method it is trying to invoke:

```
 public void Load(string xml)
{
  XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
  xDoc.LoadXml(xml);

  XmlNode settingsNode = null;
  foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.FirstChild.ChildNodes)
  {
    string name = xNode.Name;
    string wsx = xNode.ChildNodes[0].OuterXml;

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(wsx);
    DataTable dt = SampleXMLToDataTable(doc);//Where the code breaks
    XMLSample xmlWS = new XMLSample(dt, wsx, name);

    this.sample.Add(name, xmlWS);
  }
  if (settingsNode != null)
  {
    settings = GetSettings(settingsNode);
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem Solved: turns out SampleXMLToDataTable was using an unloaded assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error just means that an exception is being thrown somewhere in the invoked method.  This is exactly what you have pointed out.  Your `SampleXMLToDataTable` method is throwing an exception.  This has nothing to do with calling it via reflection.  I suspect that if you call it directly, you will get an exception in the exact same spot.

This is not a limitation of reflection, you just get a different exception because you are invoking it through reflection, though the inner exception of the `TargetInvocationException` should give you more information.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a problem calling methods from within other methods that are being called using reflection?

No, `TargetInvocationException` means that the method was successfully invoked by reflection, but that the target method threw an exception. Look at the `InnerException` property of the `TargetInvocationException` for details on the exception that was thrown by the target method.